# Django carousel display 3 images at a time

Tags: html, django

Currently I have only been able to get 1 image with this code to be active on the carousel using Django. However I want to display 3 images.

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    {% for item in page.plant_images.all %}
        {% image item.image fill-10000x10000 as img %}

        <div class="carousel-item {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}active{% endif %}">
            <img src="{{ img.url }}" class="d-block w-100"
                 alt="{{ img.alt }}">


            <div class="imageCounter">
                <img src="/media/original_images/camera.png" id="display">
                {{ forloop.counter }} of {{ page.plant_images.all.count }}

            </div>
        </div>

    {% endfor %}

</div>
```

How am I able to manipulate this so i can get the extra images?

Comment: you could take a look at boostrap owncarousel https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/demos.html. i have used it and it work perfect for me.

Comment: @ngawang13 yeah thats awesome! I've realised my javascript was the main problem